# Android appbar is overlaying when all activities extended form drawer activity

Tags: android

I have a root class

```
class DrawerLayout extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    protected void onCreateDrawer(Toolbar toolbar) {

        // drawer.
        android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout drawer = (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {...}
}
```

And when I create Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // here.
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    super.onCreateDrawer(toolbar);
}
```

When I create activity with problem:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_about);
        super.onCreateDrawer(toolbar);
}
```

How it looks:
[image: Problematic activity.]

[image: Main Activity, as expected.]

All activities are like activity_main -> app_bar_main -> content_main but with their own layouts, they do not share.

Comment: I can remove the bottom bar tho, but it will make so top bar comes above the drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` after Toolbar initialization

like this,

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: It throws an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: Adding this answer and <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> to app's theme in Styles.xml solved it! Thank you!